# Explanation of a property about euclidean distances matrices

Tags: matrices

In a paper that I'm reading, I found this sentence:

"Since distance matrices are non-singular for Euclidean distances in any space dimensions d...".

On the paper there isn't a proof, so I tried to search online but I can't find anything. Does someone know a book where I can find the proof or maybe tell me how I can show this property?